# How to to get past 30 days active branches from git?

Tags: git

Is there any git command available which shows active branches past 30 days in github ??
For eg :
git branch -r --no-merged
this command show complete active branch but i want to see only those branches which is active from 30 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are times when plain git is just not the right tool for the job and some bash-fu is needed.

```
limit=$( date -v-30d +%s )
git branch -r --no-merged | while read branch; do
    if [ $( git show --quiet --pretty="%ct" $branch ) -lt $limit ]; then
        branch $branch has been inactive for longer than 30 days
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

> `git branch -r --no-merged` [shows] complete active branch but i want to see only those branches which is active from 30 days

```
branches=`git branch -r --no-merged | awk '{print $1}'`
[[ -n $branches ]] && git log --no-walk --pretty=%D --since=30.days.ago $branches
```

or

```
branches=`git for-each-ref refs/remotes --format='%(refname)' --no-merged`
[[ -n $branches ]] && git log --no-walk --pretty=%D --since=30.days.ago $branches
```